# Return Type Issues in Java

Tags: java, arrays, double, average

I'm currently writing a simple method to average all values in an array of doubles. Here's what I have:

```
public static double mean(double[] data){
        double sum=0.0;
        for (double i:data) {
            sum+=i;
            double arrayLength= data.length;
            double avg = sum/arrayLength;
            return avg;
        }
}
```

It is telling me I am not returning type `double`, but I'm not sure how to fix this. I declared `avg` as a `double`, so why does it say this?

Answer (score 2):

The only thing that needs to be in the loop is incrementing `sum`. The rest should be moved to the end of the method:

```
public static double mean(double[] data){
    double sum=0.0;
    for (double i:data) {
        sum+=i;
    }
    double arrayLength= data.length;
    double avg = sum/arrayLength;
    return avg;
}
```

Comment: Returns a `NaN` if data.length == 0. That's correct, but needs to be documented. (Not suggesting that _you_ need to document it, just that OP needs to be aware so _they_ can document it.)

Answer (score 1):

Just think like this, what happens if data array is empty? then does `for-each` loop execute? if not, what would be returned?

You need to have a `return` statement in all possible execution paths. Add `return` statement at end of the method block, with whatever value you would like to return in case of `data` is empty/null.

Note that  `for (double i:data)` will throw `NullPointerException` in case where `data` is `null`, which is one minor issue with [enhanced-for loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/foreach.html).

Comment: `data.length` would also throw an NPE, so it isn't just an enhanced for-loop issue

Comment: @cricket_007: Isn't data.length inside for loop?

Comment: I'm saying if you did a regular `for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)` that would also throw an NPE

Comment: @cricket_007: In that case correct, both your statement and shmosel statements are correct.

Comment: Yay, you mentioned the NPE problem. Kudos!

Answer (score 1):

As Nambari said, if the array is empty you don't return anything.
But if your array contains more than two elements you do not return what you think (you return at first iteration).
You should have something like that:

```
public static double mean(double[] data){
    double sum=0.0;
    for (double i:data) {
        sum+=i;
    }

    double arrayLength= data.length;
    double avg = sum/arrayLength;
    return avg;
}
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, the average of an empty list is not 0, it is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You have the return statement inside of the for-loop. Also, to clean up the code, you could try:

```
return sum/(double)data.length;
```

Comment: Thank you. I am new to java and didn't realize I had the return statement in the loop!

Comment: One of my professors always said to put the return statement in the method with a dummy value before doing the code, that way you are sure it is in the right place.  Hope that helps prevent any future errors!

Answer (score 0):

```
public static double mean(double[] data){
    double sum=0.0;

    // Previously this loop would make the variables everytime and return
    // on the first execution
    for (double i:data) {
        sum+=i;         
    }
    // this code has been moved outside the loop which sums the array
    double arrayLength= data.length;
    double avg = sum/arrayLength;
    return avg;
}
```

So previously you declared `double avg` and `double arrayLength` on every exection of the for loop. You also had a `return avg` statement which would stop the for loop from ever running more than 1 time.

If you moved these three lines outside the for loop it would work fine!

Answer (score 0):

The point is that there is an execution path in your method that does not return any value from the method (if the array is empty).

I agree that the error message could be a bit more clear about it. Actually, that is Eclipse error message, if you compile the class manually with `javac` you will get: `error: missing return statement`, which is IMHO a bit more suitable for this case.

Just for the consistency, the equivalent one-liner in java 8 is:

```
public static double mean1(double[] data){
    return Arrays.stream(data).average().orElse(0);
}
```

so for the sake of brevity and readability I suggest you go this way if you use java 8.